# How to set gui languages to english in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have installed a german version of MS Office Professional. How can I get away from the german translation of all GUI elements.

I like to see the english names of the properties, like I have to use in VBA and find them in the Dokumentation.

Edit:

My Solution: I downloaded

- SW_DVD5_Office_Professional_Plus_2016_W32_English_MLF_X20-41353.ISO
- SW_DVD9_Office_Multi_Lang_Pack_2016_W32_MultiLang_Disk_1_MLF_X20-42853.ISO

from Microsofts Software Portal (https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/Downloads/DownloadsAndKeys.aspx).

I first install the eng-Version of Office and than the german language pack. I now can switch between two languages like I want.

[image]

Comment: Opening the online help for e.g. a property in form design view will show the English name.

Comment: ok, just pressing F1. Helps alot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way other than install a *US version* of Access/Office on another (virtual) machine.

That's what I've done.

Comment: I am not sure, if my key german key will work. I also have to find a place to download the us-version.

Comment: I don't think it will. You may need an Office 365 subscription.

Comment: I was able to downlod MS Office in english language in Microsofts portal. The key works fine. There are also Languagepacks that you can't find in the open net.

Comment: Oh, great! You could add those links to your question for reference.